# Setting PointGrey camera parameters?

Tags: ros, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Am bit confuse on where and how to modify Cameleon 3 camera parameters. For example, in `PointGrey,cfg`, there seems to be three different values... Why not only one

```
gen.add("frame_rate",         double_t, SensorLevels.RECONFIGURE_RUNNING,    "Camera speed (frames per second).",                                            100, 0, 100)
```

Also please, how to set the values in  `camera.launch` instead of  `PointGrey,cfg`, so as to avoid the need of compiling after each modification?

Am particularly interested in frame_rate, exposure, shutter speed, and image size...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239227/setting-pointgrey-camera-parameters?/) by [polar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26882/polar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably the easiest way to do this will be to use [rqt_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure), where you should be able to access and change your camera's parameters. I used it for the Chameleon 3 camera, and it worked pretty much out of the box.

---

Originally posted by [donald](https://answers.ros.org/users/24812/donald/) with karma: 61 on 2016-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-25**:
It works but you have to launch that everytime.. Do you know how to set the desire frame rate to be launched by default?